# Consider items of the same value when deciding rank

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In spark, I would like to count how values are less or equal to other values. I tried to accomplish this via ranking but rank produces
`[1,2,2,2,3,4] -> [1,2,2,2,5,6]`
while what I would like is
`[1,2,2,2,3,4] -> [1,4,4,4,5,6]`

I can accomplish this by ranking, grouping by the rank and then modifying the rank value based on how many items are in the group. But this is kind of clunky and it's inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: Added minimal example of what I'm trying to accomplish

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rank
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window


object Question extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Question").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val win = Window.orderBy($"nums".asc)

  Seq(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4)
    .toDF("nums")
    .select($"nums", rank.over(win).alias("rank"))
    .as[(Int, Int)]
    .groupByKey(_._2)
    .mapGroups((rank, nums) => (rank, nums.toList.map(_._1)))
    .map(x => (x._1 + x._2.length - 1, x._2))
    .flatMap(x => x._2.map(num => (num, x._1)))
    .toDF("nums", "rank")
    .show(false)
}
```

Output:

```
+----+----+
|nums|rank|
+----+----+
|1   |1   |
|2   |4   |
|2   |4   |
|2   |4   |
|3   |5   |
|4   |6   |
+----+----+
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Is that relevant? My code doesn't have a bug, I just don't know how to efficiently accomplish this. I'm happy to post an example of ranking then grouping but I don't see how it'll help answer the question.

Comment: Yes, it's relevant. We can't tell you what you're doing wrong if we don't know what you're doing at all. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for what constitutes a good question.

Comment: @erip Sorry about the delay. I've posted some sample code which accomplishes what I want. Thank you for the link. I'll make sure my questions are of higher quality going forwards.

Comment: I don't really see what the question is given that it appears to work. I find it an excellent question and will upvote. Try explain and try at scale.

Comment: Pretty smart, to say the least! And educational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions

```
scala> val df =  Seq(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4).toDF("nums")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [nums: int]

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl")

scala> spark.sql(" with tab1(select nums, rank() over(order by nums) rk, count(*) over(partition by nums) cn from tbl) select nums, rk+cn-1 as rk2 from tab1 ").show(false)
18/11/28 02:20:55 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+----+---+
|nums|rk2|
+----+---+
|1   |1  |
|2   |4  |
|2   |4  |
|2   |4  |
|3   |5  |
|4   |6  |
+----+---+


scala>
```

Note that the df doesn't partition on any column, so spark complains of moving all data to single partition.

**EDIT1:**

```
scala> spark.sql(" select nums, rank() over(order by nums) + count(*) over(partition by nums) -1 as rk2 from tbl ").show
18/11/28 23:20:09 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+----+---+
|nums|rk2|
+----+---+
|   1|  1|
|   2|  4|
|   2|  4|
|   2|  4|
|   3|  5|
|   4|  6|
+----+---+


scala>
```

**EDIT2:**

The equivalent df version

```
scala> val df =  Seq(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4).toDF("nums")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [nums: int]

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

scala> df.withColumn("rk2", rank().over(Window orderBy 'nums)+ count(lit(1)).over(Window.partitionBy('nums)) - 1 ).show(false)
2018-12-01 11:10:26 WARN  WindowExec:66 - No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+----+---+
|nums|rk2|
+----+---+
|1   |1  |
|2   |4  |
|2   |4  |
|2   |4  |
|3   |5  |
|4   |6  |
+----+---+


scala>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer but the one I posted below ended up being more efficient for my large dataset.

Comment: Glad that it worked.. I just edited to move all calculations in one go.. could you please try that?..

Comment: @stack0114106  I cannot get that warning to show in databricks with spark 2.3. Only if I do the explain. Your version is ?

Comment: It is spark 2.1.0

Comment: Your updated answer is faster then my answer. Nice work! I really appreciate it. If you could post a version that works off of a dataset rather then spark sql, that'd be amazing. I can also post it myself but I don't want to take credit for your solution. Either way, I'm marking your answer as correct.

Comment: sure..I'll add the df version also.. btw keep in mind that there will be no difference between them.. just a matter of style..

Answer (score 0):

So, a friend pointed out that if I just calculate the rank in descending order and then for each rank do `(max_rank + 1) - current_rank`. This is a much more efficient implementation.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rank
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window


object Question extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Question").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._


  val win = Window.orderBy($"nums".desc)
  val rankings = Seq(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4)
    .toDF("nums")
    .select($"nums", rank.over(win).alias("rank"))
    .as[(Int, Int)]

  val maxElement = rankings.select("rank").as[Int].reduce((a, b) => if (a > b) a else b)

  rankings
    .map(x => x.copy(_2 = maxElement - x._2 + 1))
    .toDF("nums", "rank")
    .orderBy("rank")
    .show(false)
}
```

Output

```
+----+----+
|nums|rank|
+----+----+
|1   |1   |
|2   |4   |
|2   |4   |
|2   |4   |
|3   |5   |
|4   |6   |
+----+----+
```

Comment: How much more efficient? I quite liked your answer as well.